# Model directory expected to contain the 'export.meta' file

Tags: google-cloud-ml

During the creation of a new version for a model after the selection of a bucket and folder I got this error from the Cloud Console.

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Field: version.deployment_uri Error: The model directory gs://ml-codelab/v1-output/ is expected to contain the 'export.meta' file. Please make sure it exists and Cloud ML service account cloud-ml-service@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com has read access to it",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
        "field": "version.deployment_uri",
        "description": "The model directory gs://ml-codelab/v1-output/ is expected to contain the 'export.meta' file. Please make sure it exists and Cloud ML service account cloud-ml-service@xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com has read access to it"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a meta graph when you export your model. You can do this using a saver e.g.

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, os.path.join(FLAGS.output_dir, "export"))
```

Typically you save the session and graph separately because your serving graph can be different from the training graph.